# Como validar cajas de texto, que solo admita numeros

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo 3 cajas de texto donde solo deberia ingresar numeros y que si se escribe una letra simplemente no la muestre, como si no la hubiera digitado. Para Windows forms

```
private void TBCausacion_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Es winforms, WPF o ASP?
Nos ayudarias mucho con estos detalles.

Comment: Para Windows forms

Comment: Si pegan texto en tu input esto ya no lo controlaría

Comment: Veo muy seguido esta misma pregunta y aun no entiendo porque la gente no utiliza el control NumericUpDown que ya viene incluído en el framework. No solo te permite capturar solo números, y tiene unos muy utiles botones para aumentar y disminuir la cantidad, sino que también te permite establecer límites y no tienes que castear nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con agregando esto a tu metodo amigo.

```
private void TBCausacion_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Espero te ayude.

Saludos.

Comment: Si perfecto, Muchas Gracias pachecoton

Comment: Agradeceria que marques la respuesta como util si te fue de ayuda mi estimado.

Comment: Debo esperar cierto tiempo para marcar la respuesta